# How to attach onclick event to an element dinamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to trigger an event attached to a html  tag

This table is builded insde a function

```
    function detail(id){
      console.log(id)
    }

function search(data){
                $.post(url, {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(data) {

                    data = JSON.parse(data);

                        $.each(data, function(i, val){

                                id = val.id;


                                html += '<tr onclick="detail('+id+')">';
                                html += '<tr>';
                            }
                        });      

                 }); 
}
```

But when I click the  element I get this err:

Uncaught ReferenceError: detallePaciente is not defined

when is actually defined in my file

any idea how could I solve this?

Comment: function detail(data)?????

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: detallePaciente is not defined` yet your function is called `detail` and nowhere does it say `detallePaciente`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
html += '<tr class="clickedclass" data-id = "' + id + '">';
```

And make alert from this in Jquery:

```
$("body").on("click", ".clickedclass", function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  console.log(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your function declaration.

It should be:

```
function detail(data) {
...
}
```

Same error with the `search` function. Would need to see how you attach it to the click event to help with that.